# How to set secure flag for cookies in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, cookies, https, setcookie

how can i set secure flag for all cookies on my wordpress site?

[cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYikG.png)

I add this in wp_config.php but its do nothing

```
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
```

Comment: is your website https? it force everything to load as https as well when you have a SSL cert ( or else it will not load otherwise in most browser ) Otherwise it just looks like you are not calling these resources in https. has nothing to do with your wp config

Comment: Yes website running https with valid SSL cert

Comment: is your website set to https only then? I see your site is loading everything none https.